# Issues with text size and alignment in EditText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, rich-text-editor, text-alignment, text-formatting

I'm developing simple rich text editor for my android application. It's based on `EditText`.

I have a problem with test sizes and alignment. When I decorated a text with `AbsoluteSizeSpan`, it was displayed properly at first time. Then I saved this text using `Html.toHtml(...)`. It was converted to something like this `<font size="1">sample text</font>`. When I opened this text in `EditText` using `Html.fromHtml(...)` all text had the same size.

The same problem with text alignment using `AlignmentSpan`...

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I've been having the same problem. May i know if you've solved it and how?